# Python easy way to read all import statements from py module

Tags: python, python-2.7, mox

I am trying to create a helper function to read a file and mock out all imports for a unit test.  I have to read the file vs import since i dont have those things on python path.

Example code:

---

```
#module.py
import com.stackoverflow.question
from com.stackoverflow.util import test_func
from com.stackoverflow.util import TestClass
```

---

```
#magic helper: what i want
magic = process('<path_to>/module.py')
for module in magic.modules_as_strings():
    #todo  would have to recuirsively add each path
    # so i would first create com, then com.stackoverflow, etc
    setattr(self, module, StubModules(module)
for obj in magic.sink:
    #these would be "from"  from x import Y
    #its basically just creating self.Y = object
    setattr(self, object)
```

Above is the mock code, I am really looking for the best way to just tokenize the file for "from/import statements"

That make sense?  I know I could read the file line by line, but I was hoping for a cleaner/concise way.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Could you add an example output of the magic calls (data structures)?

Comment: sorry i missed this but i was just expecting the string  fully qualified module so something like a.b.c.module_name .  I was going to tokenize it..

Comment: I hope my solution will work as well. You can always strip out the unnecessary pieces.

Comment: Yea, I can defiantly work with what you gave me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using the [AST](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module, it is pretty easy:

```
import ast
from collections import namedtuple

Import = namedtuple("Import", ["module", "name", "alias"])

def get_imports(path):
    with open(path) as fh:        
       root = ast.parse(fh.read(), path)

    for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(root):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Import):
            module = []
        elif isinstance(node, ast.ImportFrom):  
            module = node.module.split('.')
        else:
            continue

        for n in node.names:
            yield Import(module, n.name.split('.'), n.asname)
```

For a module like this:

```
from coco import bunny
from coco.bungy import carrot
from meta import teta
from rocket import spaceship as sp
import bingo
import com.stackoverflow
import motorbike as car
import module1, module2

s="a random variable"

def func():
    """And a function"""
```

The output is:

```
>>> for imp in get_imports("/path/to/file.py"): print imp
Import(module=['coco'], name=['bunny'], alias=None)
Import(module=['coco', 'bungy'], name=['carrot'], alias=None)
Import(module=['meta'], name=['teta'], alias=None)
Import(module=['rocket'], name=['spaceship'], alias='sp')
Import(module=[], name=['bingo'], alias=None)
Import(module=[], name=['com', 'stackoverflow'], alias=None)
Import(module=[], name=['motorbike'], alias='car')
Import(module=[], name=['module1'], alias=None)
Import(module=[], name=['module2'], alias=None)
```

Comment: Hmmph.  I beat you by 81 seconds but yours is prettier.  +1.

Comment: Thanks! ;-) I was waiting for a reply from the OP and eventually gave up when I saw that you've already replied… :-P

Comment: You should use `ast.walk` if you have code that does this sort of thing:

    if something:
        import xxxx

Comment: Thankfully, `ast.walk` is a straight swap for `ast.iter_child_nodes` in this code.  Walk is recursive, iter_child_nodes is not, and will not drop down a single block level (never mind infinitely).  So, along with conditional imports, this is also an issue for code e.g. `try: import xxxx`.  Walk will report that import, iter_child_nodes will not.

Comment: Any way to exclude the python standard library?