# Getting the list of classes in a given Python file

Tags: python, inspect

My goal is to fetch the list classes defined in a given Python file.

Following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796247/4061181), I have implemented the following:

File b.py:

```
import imp
import inspect

module = imp.load_source("__inspected__", './a.py')
class_members = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass)
for cls in class_members:
    class_name, class_obj = cls
    member = cls[1]
    print(class_name)
```

File a.py:

```
from c import CClass


class MyClass:
    name = 'Edgar'

    def foo(self, x):
        print(x)
```

File c.py:

```
c_var = 2

class CClass:
   name = 'Anna'
```

I have two issues with this implementation.
First, as [is mentioned in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module-in-python#comment27070735_1796247), classes of imported module are printed out as well. I can't understand how to exclude them
Second, looks like the `imp` file is depreciated in favour of `importlib`, but the doc seems sketchy. And I can't figure out how to refactor my solution. Any hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to use `importlib` similarly to how you're using `imp`, you can look at this: [Python 3.4: How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381264/python-3-4-how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)
and you get something like the following:

```
import importlib.machinery
import inspect

module = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader("a", './a.py').load_module()
class_members = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass)
```

### Solution #1: Look up class statements in the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST).

Basically you can parse the file so that you can get the class declaration statements.

```
import ast

def get_classes(path):
    with open(path) as fh:        
       root = ast.parse(fh.read(), path)
    classes = []
    for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(root):
        if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
            classes.append(node.name)
        else: 
            continue
    return classes
    
for c in get_classes('a.py'):
    print(c)
```

---

### Solution #2: Look at imports and ignore import from statements.

This is more in-line with your current approach, but is a little jankier.
You can look for things imported by the file you're looking at and select out the import from statements ([Python easy way to read all import statements from py module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008451/python-easy-way-to-read-all-import-statements-from-py-module)) and just make sure that none of the things imported show up later:

```
import ast
from collections import namedtuple

Import = namedtuple("Import", ["module", "name", "alias"])

def get_imports(path):
    with open(path) as fh:        
       root = ast.parse(fh.read(), path)

    for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(root):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Import):
            # We ignore direct imports
            continue
        elif isinstance(node, ast.ImportFrom):  
            module = node.module.split('.')
        else:
            continue
        for n in node.names:
            yield Import(module, n.name.split('.'), n.asname)

imported = set()
for imp in get_imports('a.py'):
    imported_classes.add(imp.name[0] if not imp.alias else imp.alias)
```

Then you can just filter out the imported things you saw.

```
for c in class_members:
    class_name, class_obj = c
    member = c[1]
    if class_name not in imported:
        print(class_name)
```

Note that this currently doesn't distinguish between imported classes and imported functions, but this should work for now.

Comment: Andrew, I know that this is beyond the asked question, still can you tell me please going for the first approach with AST, how can I fetch the class itself by its name without having to load the module ?

Comment: Python has a module that processes Python's abstract syntax grammar (so like the structure of the file as it relates to the Python programming language). You just give it a file and it processes the file. This means that it'll read all the things like class definitions, variable instantiations, imports, and whatnot. We care about the `ClassDef`s when they show up because those are the classes that are defined in the module. You can read more about the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html