# Fetching classes from a module without actually having to run the file

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Going on [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69603518/getting-the-list-of-classes-in-a-given-python-file), my goal now is to parse a Python file, and to

1. Extract all classes
2. Extract the list of its attributes and list of bases classes

**Without** loading the file (running it).

Currently, I have this working code:

parser.py

```
import ast

def get_classes(path):
    with open(path) as fh:        
       root = ast.parse(fh.read(), path)
    classes = []
    for node in ast.iter_child_nodes(root):
        if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
            classes.append(node.name)
        else: 
            continue
    return classes
    
for c in get_classes('a.py'):
    print(c)
```

File to be parsed:

```
from c import CClass
    
class MyClass(UndefinedClass):
    name = 'Edgar'

    def foo(self, x):
        print(x)


def func():
    print('Hello')
```

The good part of this solution is that I get the list of class names even given that file a.py contains invalid python code. Looks like I have to dig deeper into AST module. Is there any way I can extract the list of class attributes and its base classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to traverse the `ast` produced by `ast.parse`. The solution below performs this search not only in the main input file but in any subsequent imported files as well:

```
import ast, importlib
class Parse:
   def __init__(self):
      self.c = {}
   def walk(self, tree, f = None):
      if isinstance(tree, ast.ClassDef):
         self.c[tree.name] = {'bases':[i.id for i in tree.bases], 'attrs':[]}
         for i in tree.body:
             self.walk(i, tree.name)
      elif isinstance(tree, (ast.ImportFrom, ast.Import)):
         for i in (k if isinstance((k:=getattr(tree, 'module', tree.names)), list) else [k]):
             with open(importlib.machinery.PathFinder().find_module(getattr(i, 'name', i)).get_filename()) as f:
                self.walk(ast.parse(f.read()))
      elif isinstance(tree, ast.Assign) and f is not None:
         self.c[f]['attrs'].append(tree.targets[0].id)
      else:
         for i in getattr(tree, '_fields', []):
            for j in (k if isinstance((k:=getattr(tree, i)), list) else [k]):
               self.walk(j, None)
```

---

Putting it all together with your two original files:

File c.py:

```py
c_var = 2

class CClass:
   name = 'Anna'
```

File a.py:

```py
from c import CClass
    
class MyClass(UndefinedClass):
    name = 'Edgar'

    def foo(self, x):
        print(x)


def func():
    print('Hello')
```

```
p = Parse()
with open('a_mod_test.py') as f:
   p.walk(ast.parse(f.read()))

print(p.c)
```

Output:

```
{'CClass': {'bases': [], 'attrs': ['name']}, 'MyClass': {'bases': ['UndefinedClass'], 'attrs': ['name']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ClassDef` node has a `bases` attribute which is a list of nodes representing the base classes for the class.  It also has a `body` attribute which is a list of nodes representing the body of the class definition.  I suppose you want the `Assign` nodes in the body, but maybe you mean something slightly different by class attributes.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.ClassDef

Comment: Yes, I guess this is ClassDef. Can you provide a working example of how can I loop through all classes and get the list of bases  ? The doc is extremely sketchy on this... (